# Cannot use header enum

Tags: c, header, enums, constants

I would like to do following:

**parser.h**

```
#ifndef WS_PARSER_H
#define WS_PARSER_H
#include <stdin.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef enum {
    FIN = 0x80;
    RSV1 = 0x40
    /* ... */
} ws_flags;

#endif
```

**parser.c**

```
#ifndef WS_PARSER
#define WS_PARSER
#include "parser.h"

ws_read_fin_flag(unsigned char * chunk) {
    return (bool) chunk[0] & WS_FLAGS.FIN;
}

#endif
```

Unfortunately I get that FIN is a undeclared identifier.

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE:**

What is the convention for global enums?

```
typedef enum {} WS_FLAGS;
```

Comment: Hard to see typo. You should be using a decent IDE so theses typos would be highlight as you type. Try eclipse.

Comment: This means you can refer `WS_FLAGS` without enum qualifier e.g defined variable of type `WS_FLAGS flag=FIN;`, **Don't correct your question from answer**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan does this meet the conventions? or should I use a macro map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#ifndef WS_PARSER_H
#define WS_PARSER_H
#include <stdin.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef enum {
    FIN = 0x80,
    RSV1 = 0x40,
    /* ... */
} ws_flags;

#endif
```

It's an `,` instead of `;`.

Comment: FOR OP: don't add `,` after `RSV1 = 0x40,` also, if its last.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Why not? It's legal C syntax. And it simplifies things.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes, I'm sure. ISO/IEC 9899:1999, 6.7.2.2, says so. See e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: @undur_gongor Waw..Nice! I also [checked here](http://codepad.org/jATwfpRs) Thanks for the information and one special thanks for the book :)

Answer (score 3):

Few points:

1) your enum has ; in the middle of it, please remove all of those.

```
typedef enum {
    FIN = 0x80,
    RSV1 = 0x40
    /* ... */
} ws_flags;
```

2) no need for a

```
#ifndef WS_PARSER
#define WS_PARSER
#endif
```

at the top of c files, those are protection against include the same definitions, you normally do not include a c file or a cpp file, do not need those in source files.

3) instead of

```
#ifndef WS_PARSER_H
#define WS_PARSER_H
```

at the top of files you can use the

```
#pragma once
```

which does the same thing and is supported by most compliers today

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef WS_PARSER
#define WS_PARSER
```

Putting this in the .c file is going to cause the contents of the .h to be ignored, because the .h file has the same include guard.

You should only put include guards in .h files.

Comment: FYI... I don't know if there has been an edit to the original question but he actually has `WS_PARSER_H` in his header, which is different than `WS_PARSER`.  So, the .h will not be ignored (although there is no need to put `#ifndef WS_PARSER` in the .c file).